# What is the difference between Application vs Site Diagnostics on Azure Websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[image]

what's the difference between these two, please?

NOTE: I'm not talking about the *storage medium* (I know the diff between FS/TS/BS, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

site diagnostics is your typical web server logging (e.g., failed request tracing, http errors, etc...)

application diagnostics are the one's produced by the web app itself, i.e, Trace info, etc...